# Android Min3d doesn't support particle effect?

Tags: android, 3d, particles

I want to make a 3d game on the android. So I chose the min3d framework.

But now I found that the min3d doesn't support the 3d effect (particles and material animations).

I dissapointed with the min3d, and going to change the framework.

Please help me. What's the most available framework for me?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use AndEngine, this [project](https://github.com/pocmo/AndEngine-ParticleSystem-Demos) can help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And can I use the AndEngine and the min3d together in an project?

Comment: try to change lib folder with libs, add jar to your buildpath